# MySql update Query For Multiple rows Update

Tags: mysql, updates

I have value in column `seq_id = {18,19,20,21,22,23,24}`

I want to update this by `{19,20,21,22,23,24,18}`

I want to update this column only .other columns remain as it is.
How can i update this in mysql query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET seq_id = seq_id + 1
WHERE seq_id BETWEEN 18 AND 23

UPDATE yourTable
SET seq_id = 18
WHERE seq_id = 24
```

Comment: It is giving two duplicates.

Comment: Is this column an identity or auto increment column?  Did you omit this information from your question?